# How to delete elements of a set with composite primary key in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss6.x

I have the following entities:

```
@Embeddable
public class Noticia_i18nPK implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4556976991711237055L;

private Noticia noticia;
private String codigoIdioma;


public Noticia_i18nPK() {}

public Noticia_i18nPK (Noticia noticia, String codigoIdioma) {
  this.noticia      = noticia;
  this.codigoIdioma = codigoIdioma;
}

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="noticia_id")
@NotNull
public Noticia getNoticia() {
    return noticia;
}

public void setNoticia (Noticia noticia) {
    this.noticia = noticia;
}

@Column(name = "codigoidioma")
@NotNull
public String getCodigoIdioma() {
    return codigoIdioma;
}

public void setCodigoIdioma (String codigoIdioma) {
    this.codigoIdioma = codigoIdioma;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 31;

    result += (codigoIdioma == null) ? 0 : codigoIdioma.hashCode();
    result += (noticia == null) ? 0 : noticia.getId().intValue();
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)  return true;
    if (obj == null)  return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Noticia_i18nPK other = (Noticia_i18nPK) obj;
    if (codigoIdioma == null) {
        if (other.getCodigoIdioma() != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigoIdioma.equals (other.getCodigoIdioma()))
        return false;

    if (noticia == null) {
        if (other.getNoticia() != null)
            return false;
    } else if (noticia.getId().compareTo (other.getNoticia().getId()) != 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

The internationalization POJO:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Noticia_i18n")
 public class Noticia_i18n implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 9093075808608249854L;

private Noticia_i18nPK noticia_i18nPK;
private String descripcion;


@EmbeddedId
public Noticia_i18nPK getNoticia_i18nPK() {
    return noticia_i18nPK;
}

public void setNoticia_i18nPK (Noticia_i18nPK noticia_i18nPK) {
    this.noticia_i18nPK = noticia_i18nPK;
}

@Column(name="descripcion")
@Length(max=5000)
@NotNull
public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion (String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return noticia_i18nPK.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)  return true;
    if (obj == null)  return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Noticia_i18n other = (Noticia_i18n) obj;
    if (noticia_i18nPK == null) {
        if (other.getNoticia_i18nPK() != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!noticia_i18nPK.equals (other.getNoticia_i18nPK()))
        return false;

    return true;
}
}
```

And the POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="noticia")
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "noticia_id_seq",
    sequenceName = "ef.noticia_id_seq",
    allocationSize=1)
public class Noticia extends AuctionsBaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5402495697859251461L;

private Long id;
private Date fecha;
private Set<Noticia_i18n> noticia_i18n;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "noticia_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

@JoinColumn(name="noticia_id")
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
public Set<Noticia_i18n> getNoticia_i18n() {
    return noticia_i18n;
}

public Noticia_i18n getNoticia_i18n (String codigoIdioma) {
    getNoticia_i18n();

    if (!VacioHelper.esVacio (this.noticia_i18n)) {
        for (Noticia_i18n i18nActual : this.noticia_i18n) {
            if ((i18nActual.getNoticia_i18nPK() != null) &&
                (i18nActual.getNoticia_i18nPK().getCodigoIdioma().compareTo (codigoIdioma) == 0))
                return i18nActual;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void setNoticia_i18n (Set<Noticia_i18n> noticia_i18n) {
    this.noticia_i18n = noticia_i18n;
}

public void addNoticia_i18n (Noticia_i18n noticia_i18n) {
    if (noticia_i18n != null) {
        if (this.noticia_i18n == null)
            this.noticia_i18n = new HashSet<Noticia_i18n>();

        noticia_i18n.getNoticia_i18nPK().setNoticia (this);
        this.noticia_i18n.add (noticia_i18n);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, how I can delete a noticia_i18n element? If I get a **noticia** with three noticia_i18n elements, for example, like this:

```
EntityManager em;
....
noticia = DaoFactory.getDefault().getNoticiaDao().findById (em, noticiaActual.getIdNoticia());
...
```

If I try to remove a **noticia_i18n** entity:

```
Noticia_i18n traduccionNoticia = noticia.getNoticia_i18n (noticiaActual.getCodigoIdioma());
DaoFactory.getDefault().getNoticia_i18nDao().remove (em, traduccionNoticia);
```

I get the error:

```
deleted entity passed to persist Noticia_i18n#<null>
```

But If I add the code (before **remove**):

```
noticia.getNoticia_i18n().remove (traduccionNoticia);
```

The error is with update, because Hibernate try to update the Noticia_i18n with a null value of noticia_id.

The question is:  How to delete elements of this collection? What changes are needed in the mapping of classes?